# Diagnosing 'CodeContracts requires unproven: constructor != null'?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, code-contracts

I have several methods that report the warning *"Code Contracts: requires unproven: constructor != null"* when the C# [CodeContracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) static checker is enabled.

These particular methods do not declare any contracts, and are not called by any methods that do.

If I double-click the warnings, visual studio directs me to the line instantiating an `IQueryable<TEntity>` object. Here's one of the offending methods:

```
public List<IStudentTermData> GetAllActive()
{
    using (IObjectContext context = ContextFactory.Create())
    {
        var studentTermDataSet = context.ObjectSet<IStudentTermData>();
        var studentSet = context.ObjectSet<IStudent>();

        // Helps out CodeContracts static checker
        if(studentSet == null || studentTermDataSet == null)
            return new List<IStudentTermData>();

        // Selecting the warning brings me to the next line
        IQueryable<IStudentTermData> query =
            from studentTermData in studentTermDataSet
            join student in studentSet 
            on studentTermData.StudentId equals student.Id
            where (student.Active) select studentTermData;

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

I have several other very similar methods that do not exhibit this warning, and I noticed they do not use a LINQ join. I'm guessing that my LINQ query is being deconstructed into some (possibly null) `IQueryable` object that gets `Join()` called on it, causing this warning.

What does this have to do with the CodeContracts static checker? Also, why is the checker complaining, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: maybe check query for null equality before calling ToList()?

Comment: I tried that, but Resharper said the expression `(query != null)` will always evaluate to true. I even ignored Resharper's advice and rebuilt with a null check on query, and it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a bug here.

Your query desugars to:

```
IQueryable<IStudentTermData> query =
    studentTermDataSet.Join(studentSet,
                            studentTermData => studentTermData.StudentId,
                            student => student.Id,
                            (studentTermData, student) => new {studentTermData, student})
                      .Where(s => (s.student.Active))
                      .Select(std => std.studentTermData);
```

The only parameter called "constructor" is the last parameter of the `Join` method, and indeed, if you change the code to:

```
var query =
    studentTermDataSet.Join(studentSet,
                            studentTermData => studentTermData.StudentId,
                            student => student.Id,
                            Tuple.Create);
```

then it compiles without warnings.

The difference is that the first query uses the `Join` overload which takes an `Expression` as a parameter, whereas the second one takes a `Func` (and returns an `IEnumerable`).

So I think that the support for expression trees is possibly not complete yet. You could post a question on the [Code Contracts forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/threads) to ask about this.